# C# How to find WCF IIS deployment/virtual directory at runtime to change name of log file?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, virtual-directory

I am trying to change the name of a c# WCF logfile based on the name of the IIS Virtual directory it is deployed to.

I tried to use the  Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() call but it returns the directory c:\windows\system32\inetsrv regardless which virtual directory the WCF apps was deployed to..

So should I be looking into the VirtualDirectory Class ??  Any sample code on how to find the current Virtual Directory ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
The HostEnvironment.MapPath("~"); gave me exactly what I need !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
```

gives you the same thing as the accepted answer (in a more direct way).