# Get folder on server from WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services

On the first code, on the localhost I get the Bin folder - which I expect. On the server I get an error. These are all the methods I have tried.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath 

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") 'for the root
```

Can anyone enlighten me on how I can get the root directory on the server from WCF service?

Error:

[image]

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I have no specific error message. I have not learned how to set up trace files yet. Working on that. Just wondering what the right approach would be.

Answer (score 0):

According to the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320886/c-sharp-how-to-find-wcf-iis-deployment-virtual-directory-at-runtime-to-change-na) you should use

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still throws an error which I can't define beyond the simple statement that my completed event is throwing an error. I used a Try/Catch but that does not display the error either. I guess I am going to have to trace this error down better.

Answer (score 0):

add     `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]`
to class and try